# Comparing objects in two arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to compare objects in two arrays and if they are not the same, add them to the array.
first array

```
[
  {
    "email": "a@a.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "b@b.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "c@c.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "d@d.com"
  }
]
```

secund array

```
[
  {
    "email": "v@v.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "k@k.com"
  },
  {
    "email": "g@g.com"
  }
]
```

checking function

```
if($scope.participants.length > 0){
    result.forEach(function (resultElement) {   
        if(!$scope.participants.includes(resultElement) ) {
            $scope.participants.push(resultElement);
        }
    })
    result = [];
    console.log($scope.participants);
}
```

I checked the debug and it drops on the if condition.

Comment: If one of the email values is identical in both arrays, should the new array contain that email twice? Or should the arrays merge when they are not 100% identical ( and contain duplicate email values )?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that two objects are not equal and the same.

For example {} === {} returns false

if you want to compare objects you need to compare each primitive element of each object.

Primitives include numbers, strings, booleans, etc and not objects or arrays (which are also objects).

Answer (score 0):

```js
b1 = [
    { id: 0, email: 'john@' }, 
    { id: 1, email: 'mary@' }, 
    { id: 2, email: 'pablo@' }, 
    { id: 3, email: 'escobar@' } 
  ]; 
  
 b2 = [
    { id: 0, email: 'john@' }, 
    { id: 1, email: 'mary@' }
  ];

   var res = this.b1.filter(item1 => 
  !this.b2.some(item2 => (item2.id === item1.id && item2.name === item1.name)))
  
  console.log("check more is working",res);
```

Comment: I converted your function like that `var res = $scope.participants.filter(item1 =>                          !result.some(item2 => (item2.email === item1.email))) `  but item2 is not defined in the debugger and the result has objects