# filter value from array (object) react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, object

I'm learning by coding, here i have 'allNodes' an array of objects and 'currentNodee' object, i want to check if allNodes contains 'analyser' and 'id' which is equal to 'analyser' and 'id' of 'currentNodee' then take 'analyser' value and print it, but if for example 'allNodes' has same id but its analyser is 'undefined' then do not print anything.

what am i doing wrong here ? any idea is appreciated

```js
  const allNodes = [
    { analyser: undefined, id: 7 },
    { analyser: "abc", id: 6 },
  ];

  const currentNodee = { analyser: "abc", id: 7 };

   console.log(
    allNodes.find((option: any) => {
      option.id === currentNodee.id &&
        option?.analyser === currentNodee?.analyser;
    })
  );
```

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

Comment: Be aware that `{} === {} // false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing objects in two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60564725/comparing-objects-in-two-arrays)

Comment: @evolutionxbox that is comparing two arrays with their object, here is an array of objects and another just object

Comment: Same underlying issue

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allNodes = [
    { analyser: undefined, id: 7 },
    { analyser: "abc", id: 6 },
  ];

  const currentNodee = { analyser: "abc", id: 7 };
  
  const result = allNodes.find(node => (node.analyser === currentNodee.analyser) && (node.id === currentNodee.id))

  console.log(!result ? 'No result found' : result);
```

---

Comment: how to do printing in one line for example if there is some analyser then do this, like this node.analyser ? <h1>{node.analyser} </h1>:null

Answer (score 0):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const rd = document.getElementById("rd");
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

const allNodes = [{
    analyser: undefined,
    id: 7
  },
  {
    analyser: "abc",
    id: 6
  },
];

const currentNodee = {
  analyser: "abc",
  id: 7
};

const currentNodef = {
  analyser: "abc",
  id: 6
};

const getResult = (curr) => {
  const tgt = allNodes.find(
    ({ analyser, id }) => curr.id === id
  );
  if (tgt) {
    if (
      tgt.analyser &&
      tgt.analyser === curr.analyser
    ) {
      return JSON.stringify(tgt);
    } else {
      return "print nothing";
    }
  } else {
    return "not found"
  };
};

btn.textContent = 'Search analyser id=7';
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rd.innerText = getResult(currentNodee);
});

btn2.textContent = 'Search analyser id=6';
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  rd.innerText = getResult(currentNodef);
});
```

```html
<div>
Search result: <div id="rd">empty</div>
<button id="myBtn" />
<button id="myBtn2" />
</div>
```

Printing in single line can be done using `JSON.stringify()` as demonstrated in the above code snippet.

Comment: I have added "print nothing" only as a placeholder; instead, if we simply put "" - it will work as well.